# Web infrastructure should reset "x-forwarded-*" headers?

Tags: http, nginx, haproxy, x-forwarded-for

Given a web infrastructure, with:

WEB --> HTTP PROXY --> NGINX --> PHP

We use "X-forwarded-{for,host} from Php to get the real IP and host. But sometime, we got wrong values, I discover that it's possible to set these fields like this:

```
curl -sL http://www.toto.com -H "X-Forwarded-For: 1.96.0.1"
```

As a developer, I dont have access to haproxy/nginx configuration, and our infra. guys are saying that is the developer fault.

Hence my question, the front HTTP proxy should remove user "X-forwarded" fields before proxing query to app server?

Comment: Well that is questionable because if the connection itself is coming from another proxy, and you remove those headers then you loose the client address and get the proxy address. And as such you can't trust the header as well because it can easily be spoofed, so your call

Comment: I propose to remove the header coming from web only, not from internal traffic. We have specific entrypoint for web traffic (to manage SSL).

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is assuming that the leftmost value in `X-Forwarded-For` is the client address.  That is not how it is intended to work.

`X-Forwarded-For` works by appending the address from the incoming connection onto the right of the incoming header value, if present.

The correct solution is for the application to begin reading from the **right**, eliminating trusted addresses as it moves to the left, then stopping.

**The rightmost untrusted address is the address you are looking for.**

```
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.1.5, 203.0.113.5, 10.0.0.5
```

Let's say 10.0.0.5 is the proxy.  Nginx added this address, because the connection came from the proxy.  You know this address and trust it to have always appended the address of the client it saw, so you remove it from the list.  It is not the browser.  You know, by virtue of the trust you have of this machine, that the next address to the left is true and correct and was added by the proxy.

After you remove 10.0.0.5, you find that 203.0.113.5 is now the rightmost address. Because you just removed a trusted address, you know that 203.0.113.5 is correct, but you do not recognize and thus cannot trust any further information to the left of this address.  If 203.0.113.5 is a web proxy, belonging to an external organization, then the next address to the left, 192.168.1.5, *might* be the address of the browser behind that device, or it might be forged.  Ultimately, it doesn't matter, because the rightmost untrusted address, 203.0.113.5 is the address you want.  This is the address of the external machine that connected to your stack.

You may want to log or otherwise preserve the values further to the left, but you can't make any decisions based on anything but the rightmost remaining address, after removing any trusted address,  because that is the only one that you can believe.

Importantly, you must stop further processing at the rightmost untrusted device address, because if a trusted address appears to the left of this point, then it is forged.

Comment: I think they (infra guys) have misconfigured Nginx/HAProxy, because we don't (from app) see a list, but a single IP, that can be overriden easily by setting ``x-forwarded-for`` header. So, the app must know proxy IPs :/ I dont like this approach, I prefer keep the app infra agnostic, or this is a good practice maybe?

Comment: If the proxies can be fooled by forging a header onto the request, they are definitely and without question doing something wrong.  Re: agnostic, that's fine, too,  but it means only the outermost service in your stack should add `X-Forwarded-For` to identify its client, and any internal intermediate machines should do nothing... which in turn means you lose valuable troubleshooting information about the internal routing of requests.  Your app needn't understand that `10.0.0.5` is specificallt a proxy, but rather that `10.0.0.0/16` is a trusted subnet.

Comment: HAProxy supports the `if-none` argument to `option forwardfor` to suppress the addition of a header by the proxy when one is already present, but this should **never** be used on an external-facing machine.  That is wrong at a very fundamental level.